# what are value members in scaladocs

Tags: scala, scaladoc

I am trying to dig scala deeper but scaladocs is not straight as javadocs. While doing some mathematical operation I visited to scala.math [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/rc2/scala/math/package.html) package.
I am not able to understand value member in the docs.please suggest some guide line to decipher scaladocs. It may be a silly question but as a newbie please suggest something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/packageobjects/packageobjects.html:

> Any kind of definition that you can put inside a class, you can also put at the top level of a package. If you have some helper method you'd like to be in scope for an entire package, go ahead and put it right at the top level of the package
>
> To do so, put the definitions in a package object. Each package is allowed to have one package object.

So - the Scaladoc for `scala.math` package divides members of this package to **Type Members** (classes, just like in Java) and **Value Members** (`object`s, `def`s, `val`s and `var`s). You can see these members in the source code at [scala/math/package.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/math/package.scala).

Comment: Objects are value members, not type members.

Answer (score 0):

```
package object A {

  case class B(i: Int)

  Type Stb = String => Boolean      

  val s: String = "A"

  val b: Boolean = false

  val f: (String => Boolean) = s => s.isEmpty

  def d(s: String): Boolean = s.isEmpty
}
```

In this package all member classes and `Types` are `Type` members, `vals` and `def`s are `value` members.

Comment: I am talking in context of package

Comment: The same goes for package. In Scala there is a concept of a package object.